# How do I enable php modules from a docker-compose file?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get the PHP calendar module to load, and I have some issues. I've tried 2 approaches and neither seems to be working.

The first was to add the modules in an external Dockerfile-alternate, but the Dockerfile doesn't seem to be loading at all.

The second was to load it with a custom php.ini file (this file is actually being loaded because SESSION does not work if I don't load it.) In my `php.ini` file, I've added `extension=calendar.so` as well.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  php:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build:
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/:/var/www/html/
      - ./config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    container_name: php
```

**/php/Dockerfile-alternate**

```
FROM php:7.2.8-apache

COPY . var/www/html
COPY ./000-apache.conf /etc/apache2/others/000-default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite

# Comment
RUN echo 'testing' //I do not see this comment. 

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql calendar
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
getting these errors.

```
php           | PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
php           | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_pdo_mysql.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/php_pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
php           | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'calendar.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/calendar.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/calendar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/calendar.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/calendar.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, if anyone runs into this issue, this might help

I ran `docker-compose build --no-cache` which gave me some more insight into what was happening. I think the real issue was that it was just building from a cache.